# Trying to get the navigation bar to be on the same line as the website title

Tags: html, css

This is my first post on here, so please excuse me if I say something silly. I'll cut to the chase. I'm making a website, and I'm trying to get my navbar to be on the same line as the title, which consists of one h1 line and one h2 line right underneath that. Basically, I want it to change from the [way it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGDwW.png) to this [really cool better-looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsqAb.png) way!

Here's the CSS code I have corresponding to the navbar. Although, you'll probably find it easier to just check out the whole HTML and CSS code in the fiddle below. (also the navbar's all squishy due to how small the width of the preview is in jsfiddle but that's probably expected)

https://jsfiddle.net/2mtrhwyy/

```
#navul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;    
}

#navli {
    float: left;
}

#navli a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Thank you very much to anyone that takes a look at my problem in advance!

P.S. Also (and this is totally not as important so don't worry if you don't want to answer), but does everything look nice? Like the layout and color scheme and everything? I really want to make sure everything looks pleasing to the eye. Should I not use blue? Someone told me they didn't like the blue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n15vaty6/ - you can nest the titles and `nav` inside a new tag (in this example, `<header>`) and use flexbox to control the layout. Not to overwhelm you, but I recommend learning flexbox and grid as you learn page layout > https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Don't make us go off site to find important parts of the question, like HTML. Please include all relevant code in the question itself. Ideally a [MCVE].

Comment: A Side note.... id must be unique. You can not have multiple elements with id `navli` you should be using a class instead. You will get into all sorts of trouble if you try to reference  any of those elements by id using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex for that. https://jsfiddle.net/2mtrhwyy/1/

> Please view this snippet in full-screen mode

```css
#first, h1 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 text-align: left;
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 padding-bottom: 0em;
    color: #444444;
    display: inline;
}

#second, h1 {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 text-align: left;
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0em;
 padding-bottom: 0em;
    color: #4186C4;
    display: inline;
}

h2 {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 28px;
    color: #4186C4;
}

p, li {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

div ul {
    text-align: center;
 // margin-left: -15px;
 padding-top: 1em;
}

div ul li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

div ul li:first-child {
margin-left: 0px;
}

div a {
 color: inherit;
}

body {
 margin: 50px 50px;
 background-color: #fdfdfd;
    // background-image: url("bnb.png");
    // background-size: 10%;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    border-bottom: solid 0px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    margin-top: 0.4em;
    color: #444444;
}

#navul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;    
}

#navli {
    float: left;
}

#navli a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navli a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

#navli a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #4186C4;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4186C4;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>

     <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9f8fba671c.js"></script>

   <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
   <link rel="manifest" href="/assets/favicons/manifest.json">
   <link rel="mask-icon" href="/assets/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
   <meta name="theme-color" content="#0094ff">

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Christopher Trinh</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:800" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>
  
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div>
         <h1 id="first">Christopher<span id="second">Trinh</span>  </h1>
      <h3>Programmer / Writer / Optimist</h3>
      
      </div>
           <nav>
          <ul id="navul">
            <li id="navli"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="navli"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li id="navli"><a href="https://ctrinh98.github.io/blog/">Blog</a></li>
            <li id="navli"><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


      

      
   <h2>About Me</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae commodo magna, gravida tempor velit. Nam in velit auctor, tempor erat at, commodo urna. Curabitur vitae magna accumsan, imperdiet felis ac, varius justo. Praesent aliquam leo quis enim ornare, vitae posuere mi consequat. Ut diam ipsum, vulputate quis nisl id, eleifend facilisis ante. Donec vestibulum est vitae sem malesuada, sit amet faucibus tellus sagittis. Morbi fringilla in tortor ac placerat. Donec auctor vel augue vitae cursus. Suspendisse nulla metus, elementum et luctus vitae, maximus quis diam. Etiam ut congue est. Nam ut rhoncus lacus, eget pellentesque lacus. Sed auctor ut magna sed viverra. Quisque maximus hendrerit porttitor. Sed consectetur eros lectus, ut interdum orci laoreet vitae. Fusce a fringilla elit. Donec neque neque, cursus a malesuada nec, tincidunt sed sapien.</p>
      
      <h2>Experience</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae commodo magna, gravida tempor velit. Nam in velit auctor, tempor erat at, commodo urna. Curabitur vitae magna accumsan, imperdiet felis ac, varius justo. Praesent aliquam leo quis enim ornare, vitae posuere mi consequat. Ut diam ipsum, vulputate quis nisl id, eleifend facilisis ante. Donec vestibulum est vitae sem malesuada, sit amet faucibus tellus sagittis. Morbi fringilla in tortor ac placerat. Donec auctor vel augue vitae cursus. Suspendisse nulla metus, elementum et luctus vitae, maximus quis diam. Etiam ut congue est. Nam ut rhoncus lacus, eget pellentesque lacus. Sed auctor ut magna sed viverra. Quisque maximus hendrerit porttitor. Sed consectetur eros lectus, ut interdum orci laoreet vitae. Fusce a fringilla elit. Donec neque neque, cursus a malesuada nec, tincidunt sed sapien.</p>
      
   
   <h2>Major Projects</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae commodo magna, gravida tempor velit. Nam in velit auctor, tempor erat at, commodo urna. Curabitur vitae magna accumsan, imperdiet felis ac, varius justo. Praesent aliquam leo quis enim ornare, vitae posuere mi consequat. Ut diam ipsum, vulputate quis nisl id, eleifend facilisis ante. Donec vestibulum est vitae sem malesuada, sit amet faucibus tellus sagittis. Morbi fringilla in tortor ac placerat. Donec auctor vel augue vitae cursus. Suspendisse nulla metus, elementum et luctus vitae, maximus quis diam. Etiam ut congue est. Nam ut rhoncus lacus, eget pellentesque lacus. Sed auctor ut magna sed viverra. Quisque maximus hendrerit porttitor. Sed consectetur eros lectus, ut interdum orci laoreet vitae. Fusce a fringilla elit. Donec neque neque, cursus a malesuada nec, tincidunt sed sapien.</p>
   
   <!-- <h2>Get In Touch</h2> -->
   <div>
     <ul>
      <li><i class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to achieve this: 1. CSS Grid, 2. Bootstrap.

I personally recommend Bootstrap, since it's much simpler.

You could put the logo in the navbar itself and adjust the size as you wish.